# how can use insagram api on windows application?

Tags: c#, instagram-api

i like to learn how to use instagram-

Heading

api on windows application i try to search a websites and found only [asp.net](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Haroon-Said-e1d8d388) and py etc . but i want to use api on windows application like telegram messenger 
anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You use the API in the same way regardless of whether or not you have a Web application or a Windows Form / XAML. There are even [existing wrappers](https://github.com/cagrik/csharp-instagram-wrapper) you can use.

Comment: i am beginner, this sample have 2 missing dll please help me by give me a sample winform or xaml .

Comment: What dlls is it.complaining about?